# D3.js brushend function not properly called

Tags: function, d3.js, this

I made a module that draws a bar chart including a `d3.svg.brush()`. Part of my code is

```
Bar.prototype.init = function ( ) {
     //...
     this.brush = d3.svg.brush()
                     .y( this.y)
                     .on("brushend", this.brushend);
     console.log(this.brushend); // works
} 
Bar.prototype.brushend = function() {
    console.log(this.brush); // undefined. why?
}
```

To access `this.*` values, I cannot make `brushend` function a normal function by using `function brushend()` or `var brushend = function()`.

How should I call it properly?

Answer (score 0):

D3 will call the event handler provided for its `brushend` event much like event handlers for normal DOM events will get called. For standard events `this` will reference the element the event occured upon. This rule does also apply to D3's brush event handlers where `this` references the group containing the DOM elements of the brush. Obviously, this group doesn't have a property `brush` you could reference by using `this.brush` from with the handler.

A workaround would be to save your reference by using a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work):

```
Bar.prototype.init = function ( ) {
     //...
     this.brush = d3.svg.brush()
                     .y(this.y)
                     .on("brushend", this.brushend());  // Get handler by calling factory
}

// A factory returning the handler function while saving 'this'. 
Bar.prototype.brushend = function() {
    var self = this;      // Save a reference to the real 'this' when the factory is called.
    return function() {   // Return the handler itself.
         // By referencing 'self' the function has access to the preserved
         // value of 'this' when the handler is called later on.
        console.log(self.brush);
    };
}
```